# In VUetify, expansion panel header sticky not working in IE 11 browser

Tags: java, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to fix  element while scrolling its content until the next header element comes up.
I wrote code and it worked in chrome but it is not working in IE11.

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 65px;
    @media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'sm-and-down')} {
       top: 55px;
    }
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Can you please help in fixing this in IE11.

Comment: I want "expansion panel header" element sticky while scrolling its content until the next header element comes up. I wrote above code and it worked in chrome but it is not working in IE11.

Comment: Yes, because IE11 does not support `position: sticky`  as indicated by https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky. You need to use another plugin or workaround for that, e.g. https://github.com/mehwww/vue-sticky-directive

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I went through different options but none of them is working in IE11.